# Which data structure to use

Tags: java, data-structures

I need to store information about two attributes of an instance and there could be more than one of them.

So, essentially, I need to store information about two attributes for a set of objects. Which data structure should I be using? I'm using Java. Also, of the two attributes, one is a string and the other is an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an Helper class like

```
class DataRepresenterHelper {
   private String name;
   private Object foo;
   //setters + getters + constructer
}
```

and then based on the need you could store them in Map, List or  Set or something..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple Pair class that holds the two attributes and add then to a map for each object that you want to store.

If you don't want the Pair then you can have two maps each holding one attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to search by one of them? Then use a `HashMap` with that member as the key. For example if you need to search by the String:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Comment: Yes. Currently im implementing it via this approach itself. But the thing is somewhere down the line I need to get all the contents..in this case both the String and Object. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean search by something else and getting both the String and the Object?

Comment: What I meant was that at some point I need to get all the contents [value] of the map. And I do not have a handle on the key at that time.

Comment: @user815961 Each map implements `values()` which will return a Collection of all values. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model class with two attributes mentioned in your question such as String and Object as follwos

```
public class Model {

    String str;
    Object object;

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public Object getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public void setObject(Object object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

}
```

then u can use any collection framework to store the corresponding  model class object such as

```
List<Model> list=new ArrayList<Model>();
list.add(new Model());
```

and so on

Map, Set ..